# Javascript clearInterval not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, clearinterval

Whenever I run my program, It seems to work fine. I use setInterval to make the time refresh, but when I click on a different item, the old one pops up again. It's a bit hard to explain, but basically clearInterval doesn't work. Here is my code:

```js
            function days(idk) {
                clearInterval(days);
                var ver = idk;
                let date_1 = new Date('11/8/2022');
                let date_2 = new Date();
                let difference = date_1.getTime() - date_2.getTime();
                var dayHolder = document.getElementById('days');
                if (ver == 1) {
                    let TotalDays = Math.ceil(difference / 1000);
                    var text = ("There are " + TotalDays + " seconds until the Halo Infinite Winter Update.")
                    dayHolder.innerHTML = text;
                    setInterval(days, 1000, ver = 1);
                } else if (ver == 2) {
                    let TotalDays = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 60));
                    var text = ("There are " + TotalDays + " minutes until the Halo Infinite Winter Update.")
                    dayHolder.innerHTML = text;
                    setInterval(days, (1000 * 60), ver = 2);
                } else if (ver == 3) {
                    let TotalDays = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600));
                    var text = ("There are " + TotalDays + " hours until the Halo Infinite Winter Update.")
                    dayHolder.innerHTML = text;
                    setInterval(days, (1000 * 3600), ver = 3);
                } else if (ver == 4) {
                    let TotalDays = Math.ceil(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
                    var text = ("There are " + TotalDays + " days until the Halo Infinite Winter Update.")
                    dayHolder.innerHTML = text;
                    setInterval(days, (1000 * 3600, 24), ver = 4);
                }
    
            }
```

```css
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            background-image: url("cheif.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

```html
        <h1>How many days until the Halo Infinite Winter Update?</h1>
        <p id="days">Click a button!</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="days(ver = 1)">Load seconds</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="days(ver = 2)">Load minutes</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="days(ver = 3)">Load hours</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="days(ver = 4)">Load days</button>
```

Comment: `clearInterval` does not take a function as an argument - it takes a so-called "intervalID" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval#syntax ... which is returned by `setInterval` - i.e. it doesn't work like event listeners

Comment: You could eliminate the need for clearInterval and reduce the amount of code by 90 percent by making "ver" a global and using a dropdown in place of buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the ID of your interval outside the scope of your function and remove it by passing this ID to `clearInterval` function. This is how you should structure your code:

```js
let intervalID; // should be defined outside the function

function myFunction() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);

    // This is where the ID is set
    intervalID = setInterval(myFunction, delay, args);

}
```